# Low accuracy in Tensorflow Object detection api Tutorial notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, window, object-detection

I ran tensorflow object detection api tutorial [notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) and got accuracy show in image using 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17' model which is different from the [tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj3wPK3jbbsAhVBVH0KHf7HBZ0QwqsBMAF6BAgSEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DCOlbP62-B-U&usg=AOvVaw2avdDohoSj-vn_QAXkkEAw) i am following(lower to be precise).

**My question is does a model accuracy vary from system to system.**

I'm running this on window 10 pc with amd processsor(CPU only traning).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things that can influence your inference. The model of your GPU or CPU is **not** one of them. But many things can be different because you are using your CPU, like memory usage, batchsize and other things.

Tensorflow and a lot of libraries used in this object detection api tutorial has changed from 2017 (date of the video), so for a 1:1 detection you need to install the same 2017 version of the tensorflow and all of it's requirements.